# Convert to list a object with anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, mvp, anonymous-types

I need convert to list a object with anonymous type because when i databind the gridview i get

"The data source does not support server-side data paging"

or How i can solve this?

```
object o =  HttpRuntime.Cache[key];

if(o is ICollection)
{
    //Sort Object
    o = ((IQueryable)this.DataSource).AsQueryable().OrderBy(SortExpresion);

    DataSource = o;

    DataBind();

}
```

data returned from cache are ok, the problem is that i extended the gridview control and the data type of datasource is always different, and i need sort this anonymous data stored in cache and use in the gridview

Answer (score 2):

Reason is `IQueryable` does not support paging. You need to convert it to a more concrete type like `List<T>` or as **REA_ANDREW** suggested, [`PagedDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx).

### Example:

```
o = ((IQueryable)this.DataSource).AsQueryable().OrderBy(SortExpresion).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the datasource of a PagedDataSource class and then assign this object as the datasource of your gridview.  Otherwise, create an object datasource and bind that to your gridview.

Andrew